# How to fill and submit form using Python 3 and only Python 3 libraries

Tags: python-3.x, urllib

I am working on this as a free time project.

I would like to use Python 3 to login to a site (fill form and submit) and then I plan to scrape the page for some data. The reason I am strictly looking for a solution in Python 3 is because I am trying to learn more about Python and figured I would go straight to Python 3. I have seen several great looking tools such as mechanize but they only seem to support Python 2.

Planning to use this for a financial investment site but let's just use starbucks as an example.

```
def loginToStockSite(username, pwd):
    url = "https://www.starbucks.com/account/signin"
    values = {"Account.UserName" : username, 
              "Account.PassWord" : pwd}
    data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
    data = data.encode('utf-8')
    req = urllib.request.Request(url, data)
    sock = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    htmlSource = sock.read().decode('utf-8')
    return htmlSource
```

I have gotten very confused from the various encode, decode, url opener, etc. examples. I have not found a solution that has worked for me yet.

Thanks in advance for any help with my "for fun" project.

---

Update

Here is the html I get back (with a bunch cut out to fit the character limit for a question)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />

        <title>Account Sign In | Starbucks Coffee Company</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    </head>
    <div class="fields">
        <div class="region size1of1">
            <div class="validation_summary warning validation_medium"><h2>Please Enable Cookies to Continue</h2><p>To sign in to the Starbucks web site, please enable cookies in your web browser.</p></div>

        <div class="fields">
            <form action="/account/signin" class="siren region size1of2" id="accountForm" method="post">

                <fieldset class="login_position">
                    <legend class="hidden_visually">I have a Starbucks account.</legend>

                    <h2 class="existing_acc_h3">I have a Starbucks account.</h2>

                                        <div id="user_info" class="region size1of2 reset">
                                            Hi,
                                            <span id="info_user"></span>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="size1of2">
                                            <a id="not_me" href="#notme">Not You?</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div id="connect_cont" >
                                <div id="text_cont" class="hidden">
                                    <h3>Have a Starbucks account?</h3>
                                    <p>Connect your Facebook account to your Starbucks account by logging in here.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label for="Account_UserName">Username <span class="required">*</span></label>
                            <label for="Account_UserName" class="hidden">Starbucks Username <span class="required">*</span></label>
                            <input class="field_xlarge" id="Account_UserName" maxlength="200" name="Account.UserName" type="text" value="MY_USERNAME_WAS_HERE" />
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label for="Account_PassWord">Password <span class="required">*</span></label>
                            <label for="Account_PassWord" class="hidden">Starbucks Password <span class="required">*</span></label>
                            <input class="field_xlarge password" id="Account_PassWord" maxlength="200" name="Account.PassWord" type="password" value="MY_PASSWORD_WAS_HERE" />
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            Forgot your <a href="/account/forgot-username?AllowGuest=False">username</a> or <a href="/account/forgot-password?AllowGuest=False">password</a>?
                            <p class="privacy_policy hidden">
                                <a href="/about-us/company-information/online-policies/privacy-policy">Concerned about privacy?</a>
                            </p>
                        </li>
                        <li class="inline push">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="Account.IsRememberMe" name="Account.IsRememberMe" value="True" class="checkbox" />
                            <label for="Account.IsRememberMe">Keep me signed in.</label>
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                </fieldset>

                <fieldset>
                    <input id="ReturnUrl" name="ReturnUrl" type="hidden" value="" />
                    <input id="AllowGuest" name="AllowGuest" type="hidden" value="False" />
                    <input id="isJavaScriptDisabled" name="isJavaScriptDisabled" type="hidden" value="True" />
                    <span class="button"><button type="submit">Sign In</button></span>
                </fieldset>

                <fieldset class="submit">
                    <div id="fb_container">
                        <div id="fb_btn_cont">
                            Or log in using Facebook.
                            <p><a class="fb_button fb_button_medium" id="connect" href="#connect"><span class="fb_button_text">Login with Facebook</span></a></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </form>

            <div class="region size1of2 block_login">


                    <h2>I need a Starbucks account.</h2>

                        <p><span class="button"><a href="/account/create">Create An Account</a></span></p>


                    <p>With a Starbucks account you can register and manage your Starbucks Cards and participate in <a href="/card/rewards">My Starbucks Rewards</a>.</p>

                    <ul class ="basic">
                        <li>Enjoy a free drink on your birthday</li>
                        <li>Protect your balance if your Starbucks Card is missing or stolen.</li>
                        <li>Transfer money between cards.</li>
                        <li>Track your earnings in My Starbucks Rewards</li>
                        <li>Reload your Card balance automatically</li>
                    </ul>

            </div>


        </div>





                <div class="fields">
    <div class="region size1of1">
        <ul id="breadcrumb">
            <li><a href="/card">Card</a> .<ul>
                <li><a href="/card/rewards">My Starbucks Rewards</a> .<ul>
                    <li>View Your Stars</li>
                </ul></li>
            </ul></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
        </div>



    <div id="footer">
        <div class="container">

    <form id="search" method="get" action="/search">
        <fieldset>
            <input id="searchbox" name="keywords" title="Search Keyword" maxlength="100" class="search_input" />
            <span class="button button_search"><button id="submit_search_util" type="submit">Search</button></span>
        </fieldset>
    </form>


            <div class="fields">
                <div class="region size5of6 suffix1of6">
                    <div class="footer_categorical"><ol class="blocks blocks-five-up">
<li><h4>
    <a href="/shop/card">Buy a Card</a>
</h4>
</li>
<li><h4>
    <a href="/card">Manage Your Card</a>
</h4>
<ol>

    <li><a href="/Card#cardBalanceWrapper">Check Balance</a></li>
    <li><a href="/card/reload/one-time">Reload Your Card</a></li>
    <li><a href="/card/manage/transfer">Transfer Funds</a></li>
    <li><a href="/card/manage/history">View Transactions</a></li>

</ol>
</li>
<li><h4>
    <a href="/card/rewards">My Starbucks Rewards</a>
</h4>
<ol>

    <li><a href="/account/create/register">Register Your Card</a></li>
    <li><a href="/account">View Your Stars</a></li>
    <li><a href="/card/rewards/gold">Keep Your Gold Benefits</a></li>
    <li><a href="/card/rewards/rewards-program-ts-and-cs">Rewards Program Terms and Conditions</a></li>

</ol>
</li>
<li><h4>
    Learn More
</h4>
<ol>

    <li><a href="/card/card-terms-and-conditions">Card Terms and Conditions</a></li>
    <li><a href="/card/egift">What is a Starbucks Card eGift?</a></li>
    <li><a href="/customer-service/faqs/card">Card FAQs</a></li>
    <li><a href="/account">Manage Your Account</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://mystarbucksidea.force.com/ideaList?ext=0&amp;lsi=0&amp;category=Starbucks+Card">My Starbucks Idea</a></li>

</ol>
</li>
```

I expected to get back a page like I get when I login in using a browser and have a div with the current balance on whatever the default gift card is that is registered.

```
 <div class="balance-amount numbers">
```

That is the div that is visible. I found the balance in another place in the page source also but I do not see it on the page.

```
<p class="card_balance numbers">

                                <span>$27.68</span> <span class="datestamp">3/10/2013 2:12 PM</span>

                        </p>
```

Anyways, I would like to input the login info and submit the form using Python 3 or post the data somehow to login and then (as a use case but outside what is needed to answer the question) I would pull the account balance from the html.

I did find that my username and password are apparently in their corresponding fields and in the validation summary it says

```
<div class="validation_summary warning validation_medium"><h2>Please Enable Cookies to Continue</h2><p>To sign in to the Starbucks web site, please enable cookies in your web browser.</p></div>
```

I did see some examples that dealt with cookies. Is that the problem? I will research that possible solution. In the meantime, hope this helps you help me. Thanks.

Comment: Could you also include in your question what you're seeing when you run this and how that differs from what you expected?